# Xamarin iOS UIWebView: How to get custom data attribute values from URL content?

Tags: ios, xamarin, webview, xamarin.ios, uiwebview

For my Xamarin iOS app, I want to get the custom attribute value present in the URL content provided to the UIWebView.

**URL CONTENT:**

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.democlass {
    color: red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="frame" data-link="LINKER"></div>

<p id="demo"></p>

<button>Try it1</button>
<button>Try it2</button>
<p id="demoz"></p>
<button>Try it3</button>

</body>
</html>
```

**Xamarin iOS:**

```
var webView = new UIWebView();
webView.LoadRequest(new NSUrlRequest(new NSUrl(" */above html page/*")));
var url = webView.EvaluateJavascript("document.getElementsByName('div')[0].getAttribute('data-link')");
```

when I run the `EvaluateJavascript` on the `UIWebview`, I expect the `url` parameter to fetch the value `LINKER` but it is returning empty string.

Can anyone help me out? I am not sure what I'm missing or doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way :

```
var url = webView.EvaluateJavascript("document.getElementById('frame').getAttribute('data-link');");
```

#### PS:Make sure this line execute when the webview has finished loading.

My code :

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad();
    var webView = new UIWebView();
    webView.LoadRequest(new NSUrlRequest(new NSUrl(" */above html page/*")));
    web.Delegate = new myDelegate();
}

public class myDelegate : UIWebViewDelegate
{
    public override void LoadingFinished(UIWebView webView)
    {
        var str = webView.EvaluateJavascript("document.getElementById('frame').getAttribute('data-link');");
    }
}
```